# Failed to deploy Rails app with gem bootstrap-sass 3.0.3.0 on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a rails application that I wanted to upgrade from bootstrap-sass 2 to bootstrap-sass 3

After modifying some css class name, my application worked perfectly on my machine.

I removed the @import bootstrap-responsive ( because bootstrap is natively responsive since 3.0 ) I updated my gemfile and my bundle BUT when I try to deploy my application on Heroku I have the following error :

`AssetSync: using /tmp/build_68121564-cc6f-46c8-86d7-ad9ccb180ea1/config/initializers/asset_sync.rb
       rake aborted!
       File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-responsive.
       Load paths:
       Sass::Rails::Importer(/tmp/build_68121564-cc6f-46c8-86d7-ad9ccb180ea1/app/assets/stylesheets/developers.css.sass)`

What I tried so far :

- Remove gem bootstap-sass from the asset group (didn't work )
- I tried the rake tmp:clear command (didn't work either )
- Bundle updated and bundle installed everything again ( still not working )

What should I do ? 
The problem is clearly due to some temp files but even after cleaning them I can't push my app on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I just had a @import bootstrap-responsive in another .css.scss file im my repo.